# Text file does not get opened in output window.Python (Pycharm IDE)

Tags: python, file-io, pycharm

So I just began learning Python and after making a file named myfile.txt I tried running this bit of code

```
def Main():
    f=open("myfile.txt","r")
    for line in f:
        print(line)
        f.close()

    if __name__ =="__main__":
        Main()
```

The file doesn't open , I'm just left with a blank output window.Any ideas what I did wrong? I'm using the Pycharm IDE on Windows.Please help.

Comment: FIXED! Just removed f.close and used full directory name (C:\Users\username\Desktop\textfile.txt) and also unindented if.

Comment: You don't need the full directory name if your textfile is in the same directory as your Python file, unless you want to of course :)

Answer (score 3):

First you need to make sure you indentions are correct. You should not close the file when inside the loop, so it's to much indented. And to run the program your `if __name__ =="__main__":` must be defined outside the function. Try this:

```
def main():
    f = open("myfile.txt","r")
    for line in f:
        print(line)
    f.close()

if __name__ =="__main__":
    main()
```

Usually you use the keyword `with` when handling files. It manages the opening and closing for you. Everything indented inside the `with` statement is done with the file being open. Try this, it's doing exactly the same:

```
def main():
    with open("myfile.txt", "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            print(line)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

deindent the `if`

```
def Main():
    f=open("myfile.txt","r")
    for line in f:
        print(line)
        f.close()

if __name__ =="__main__":
    Main()
```

The `if` was part of your `Main` function, so you had a recursive function when the the condition was `True`

I believe you want the `if` to be tested after you define the function `Main`

Comment: You don't 'make a recursion', you make a recursive function.

Comment: fixed it, please edit my answer if you see any mistakes.